# Laplace Equation on Rectangle with Inhomogeneous Neumann BCs and PBCs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, harmonic-functions

I will preface this question by referring to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885157/laplace-equation-in-unit-square) which did not give a full solution. I found this question on the January 2017 Applied Mathematics Qualifying Exam from the University of Wisconsin-Madison, specifically question 5 of [this document](https://uwmadison.app.box.com/v/appliedmath/file/144110090770).

We wish to solve Laplace's equation $u_{xx} + u_{zz} = 0$ on a 2D rectangular domain with $x \in \left[ 0,\ L\right)$ and $z \in \left[0,\ H\right]$ with periodic boundary conditions in $x$ and the following Neumann boundary conditions at $z = 0$ and $z = H$:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
u_z(x,\ 0) &= \theta_{-},\quad 0 \leq x < l,\quad& u_z(x,\ 0) &= \theta_{+},\quad l \leq x < L,\\
 u_z(x,\ H) &= \theta_{+},\quad 0 \leq x < L - l,\quad& u_z(x,\ H) &= \theta_{-},\quad L - l \leq x < L.
\end{alignat*}

To make the solution unique, the condition $u(0,\ 0) = 0$ must also be satisfied.

There are two hints given with the problem:

(1) Rather than considering Green's functions, separation of variables, etc., think about simple solutions of $u_{xx} + u_{zz} = 0$.

(2) Draw a picture, consider the solution in different parts of the domain, and derive jump conditions to connect the different parts together.

**My Attempt**

My initial attempt was to take the hints to heart and consider piecewise linear functions of $z$ alone (with the branches dependent on $x$), since these would trivially satisfy Laplace's equation. We can define such a function to match the desired Neumann boundary conditions, but without $x$ dependence I don't believe the periodic boundary conditions can be satisfied.

Another thought I had was to take the Fourier transform in $x$, leading to the ODE
$$\hat{u}_{zz} = k^2\,\hat{u},$$
which has the solution
$$\hat{u} = \hat{f}(k)\,e^{k\,z} + \hat{g}(k)\,e^{-k\,z}.$$
The trouble I ran into with this attempt was finding the Fourier transform of the Neumann boundary conditions (and interpreting what the periodic boundary conditions would be in Fourier space).